# How to not lose data with sendHandle?

Tags: node.js, sockets

Node.js child_process docs say

> The optional sendHandle argument that may be passed to subprocess.send() is for passing a TCP server or socket object to the child process...Any data that is received and buffered in the socket will not be sent to the child.

So if pass a socket to a child process, how do I not lose the buffered data?

I called `socket.read()` on the socket before sending it to check for buffered data. It returned `null`, yet data was still lost.

How do I pass a socket from one process to another without losing data?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution is to never start reading from the socket. For example, in the [internal/cluster/round_robin_handle](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.4.0/lib/internal/cluster/round_robin_handle.js#L26-L27) module

```
this.handle = this.server._handle;
this.handle.onconnection = (err, handle) => this.distribute(err, handle);
```

This overwrites the normal processessing of new TCP handles, so a child process can do it instead.

(I would have used the `cluster` module, except I needed some customization, like least connection load balancing.)